# HTML Video tag Strange behavior when controling video progress

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-video

When I used the HTML video tag, I found that different videos have different loading behaviors.

The second strange behavior make the playback very awkward.

Both of the videos format is mp4.

[Normal behavior：The chrome browser requests video resources，the size of the resource per request is large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf2Xh.jpg)

[Strange behavior: The chrome browser keeps making requests, and there are very few resources per request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNNdm.jpg)

but Firefox rarely show this strange behavior.

Is there any principle that can explain this?